# Managing trace code in ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, logging

So I use a lot of trace-code/logging when starting a new project, or debugging an existing one. I was wondering what techniques do you use to manage it, as I always end up deleting it before doing a commit, and then have to rewrite it if ever something else goes wrong.

I was thinking about having a development branch with all the trace-code, and the master would be clean, but it seems like it would be hard to sift through what is debugging code, and what should be merged.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
def debug_only
  if $DEBUG
    yield
  end
end
...
debug_only { puts "Some tracing code." }
```

Passing `-d` on the command line will make `$DEBUG` true.

```
% ruby -e 'p $DEBUG'
false

% ruby -de  'p $DEBUG'
true
```

In that case, one possibility is to separate the tracing code from what you're tracing.

For eacample:

release.rb:

```
class A
  def stuff(a, b)
    # do stuff ...
  end
end
```

debug.rb:

```
require 'release'
class A
  alias release_stuff stuff
  def stuff(a, b)
    puts "calling stuff with (#{a.inspect}, #{b.inspect})"
    rv = release_stuff(a,b)
    puts "Done calling stuff."
    rv
  end
end
```

This has problems in that the granularity is a method, then again it may encourage you to write smaller methods. You can of course make it less verbose with some "metaprogramming".

You can also use instance_method,bind and define_method to make the copy of the old method anonymous.

And then you use it something like

```
ruby -d -rdebug program.rb
```

Comment: actually I'm already using something very similar: `def verbose() $verbose = true; yield; ensure $verbose = false end` and I have a log() function which only outputs when $verbose is true. But my problem is with the actual trace-code, it's a real mess, and I just don't want it there in production code, I'd like my code to be free of any debug-specific fluff.

Comment: aha, hadn't thought of this—it might help!